# Mass change Microsoft DNS & IIS server settings

Tags: iis, iis-6, windows-dns

I need to change about 100 DNS records and IIS configurations on a Windows 2003 web server.  The GUI doesn't accommodate it and the MS command line tools seem incomplete (for example: dnscmd cannot edit a record, only create).  Is there a third party tool out there I can use?

Basically I just need to change one IP address to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think something like [this](http://blog.geekpoet.net/2008/04/quick-and-dirty-way-to-mass-update.html) would help; you can edit the DNS file in your favorite text editor.

Comment: I ended up using dnsdump http://www.reskit.net/DNS/dnsdump.cm_ to dump the DNS config then used PSPad to do a multi file find and replace, then imported the changed config with dnsdump.

Comment: For the IIS config I created a backup configuration in IIS Manager, edited the backupname.MD0 file and then restored the backup.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy to update dns records from the powershell command line, (as I was looking up a wmi query I found someone else that already wrote the code I was writing so here's the link)

try this code: [PowerShell: Script to make batch DNS changes](http://www.atebymonsters.com/blog/2010/2/8/powershell-script-to-make-batch-dns-changes.html)

From the site:

```
$CNAMES = import-csv "Path to CSV file"
$Query = "Select * from MicrosoftDNS_CNAMEType"
Foreach($CNAME in $CNAMES)
{
$CNAME
$Record = Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\microsoftdns" -Query $Query -ComputerName dnsserver | Where-Object{$_.Ownername -match $CNAME.Aliases}
$Record.RecordData = "FQDN of new IIS server"
$Record.put()
}
```

The script can be modified to update any kind of DNS record, so it's not locked into just updated CNAME's